# A drop down list value based on another drop down list in excel

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula

I have two drop down lists in excel with same list of values (basically months of year which is fetched from a database, not relevant to the question here)

Now I want one drop down list value to change based on the value of another drop down list.

For example, consider that both lists contain values "Aug-2016" and "Jul-2016". If I select "Aug-2016" in one list the other list value should be "Jul-2016" (As in one drop down list value should be one month less than other drop down list value)

I know that it is possible through macros but any one knows if it is possible through excel formulae.

Comment: It sounds like you do not want hte list entries to change but rather to change the value of the cell holding the second list. In that case, use a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro although I wonder why the second cell holds a data validation list at all if you just want to set the value to one month previous. Perhaps discard the list and just use a formula with the [EDATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edate-function-1586b161-4361-4a6d-939b-9d96eae962a8).

Comment: Yes I know it is possibel through macros. The thing is both the list are fetched from data base and that is how they are refreshed as well (Cant help with that). So I want the values to change without affecting the way data is fetched from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. We can just use EOMONTH function in the second drop down list and that works.